# I can't load an image to change the icon of a window JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, window

I tried to make a window with an icon with JavaFx but it doesn't work.
I don't know why ? I've been testing with InputStream and I had an error also. I use URL and it doesn't work also. HELP :( please

The Main Class:

```
package fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib_test;

import fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.WindowOptions;
import fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.graphics.Base;
import fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.utils.ResourceLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Base {

    private WindowOptions windowOptions = new WindowOptions(1280, 720,  "Launcher Test", true, StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new LauncherPanel(windowOptions));

        setupWindow(stage, scene, windowOptions, ResourceLoader.loadImage("icon.png"));
    }

}
```

The ResourceLoader Class:

```
package fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.utils;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceLoader {

    private static String resourceLocation = "resources/";

    public static Image loadImage(String file) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL( "file:" + getResourceLocation() + file));
            return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void setResourceLocation(String resourceLocation) {
        ResourceLoader.resourceLocation = resourceLocation;
    }

    public static String getResourceLocation() {
        return resourceLocation;
    }
}
```

The Base Class:

```
package fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.graphics;

import fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.WindowOptions;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Base extends Application {

    private Point point = new Point();

    public abstract void start(Stage stage) throws Exception;

    protected void setupWindow(Stage stage, Scene scene, WindowOptions windowOptions) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            System.err.println("[FireLauncherLib] Can't setup the window:\n" + e);
        }

        stage.initStyle(windowOptions.getStageStyle());
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle(windowOptions.getTitle());
        stage.setWidth(windowOptions.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(windowOptions.getHeight());
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        if(windowOptions.isMovable()) {
            scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    point.x = (int)(stage.getX() - event.getScreenX());
                    point.y = (int)(stage.getY() - event.getScreenY());
                }
            });

            scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    stage.setX(event.getScreenX() + point.x);
                    stage.setY(event.getScreenY() + point.y);
                }
            });
        }

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    protected void setupWindow(Stage stage, Scene scene, WindowOptions windowOptions, Image icon) {
        setupWindow(stage, scene, windowOptions);
        stage.getIcons().clear();
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
    }

}
```

I have this error :

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1401)
    at fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.utils.ResourceLoader.loadImage(ResourceLoader.java:17)
    at fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib_test.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$10(GtkApplication.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/icon.png (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1068)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1399)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.stage.Stage$4.onChanged(Stage.java:696)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$0(TrackableObservableList.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib.graphics.LauncherBase.setupWindow(LauncherBase.java:70)
    at fr.fireblaim.firelauncherlib_test.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$10(GtkApplication.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I use Intellij IDEA 2019.3.4 Ultimate

The Resource Structure:

src
  resources
      icon.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your code - as you use the "file:" protocol - that you expect the images to be in a directory on the filesystem. So why not change the call load from File not URL:

```
File f = new File(getResourceLocation(), file);
ImageIO.read(f)
```

You can then fix the directory location issue by checking where Java thinks those files are from by calling / printing:

```
f.getAbsolutePath();
f.exists();
```

Alternatively if these images are in the same jar as your code you should be using getClass().getResourceAsStream() to locate InputStream to pass to ImageIO.read(is).

Comment: I've tested your method and it doesn't work.
I have this error:

`javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
F:\Workspace FireLauncherLib\resources\icon.png
false
`

It's strange because the file is in F:\Workspace FireLauncherLib\resources\icon.png but but he doesn't read it.

Comment: I added `System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(f.exists());` to see the file path in the console

Comment: If File object shows f.exists() is false then your path must be wrong. Check you have set up the right path to the file. You can loop though f.getParentFile() and check each level.

Comment: The problem is that the path in the code corresponds to the real path. That's really weird. I don't understand why it doesn't load the file.

Comment: It won't load the file until you resolve why f.exists() is false, as that is proof that the path have is wrong, hence java.io.FileNotFoundException. Printing f.getParentFile().exists() and so on will help you see which level may be wrong. Good luck

Comment: Ok now the file "exists". But I have now this error :\

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.java:85)`

WTF